# ES6 export and import problems

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to export functions in ES6 to access them from other files.
But I can't figure out how.

file 1: (import)

```
import components from './components/components';
console.log(components.hej);
```

file 2: (export)

```
var hej = () => {
    console.log('HEj'); 
};

export var hej;
```

Why can't I access the function "hej" declared in file 2 from file 1?
It does not make sense for me.

Please help!

Comment: Please post your directory structure.

Comment: There is no point to use function arrow, if you store function in named variable and then expose it through the variable. In this case, use standard `function hej(){ ... }`

Comment: Seems you like you didn't read about imports and exports at all. MDN has examples that show exactly what to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing a named export, not a default export, so that import syntax won't work. To import `hej` as it stands, you'd have to do:

```
// Imports a single object by name
import { hej } from './components/components';
console.log(hej);
```

Or:

```
// Imports all exported objects grouped together under the specified name
import * as components from './components/components';
console.log(components.hej);
```

Also, your export syntax isn't right - `export var hej` should be `export { hej }`, as you're not defining a new variable there, you're using the existing one. Alternatively, you could change your function declaration to `export var hej = () => { ... };`, and that would have the same effect.

Comment: Ah, i see. Thanks alot dude. This really helped me.

Comment: @user2952238: Glad I could help. I'd definitely recommend reading the link that Felix Kling posted in the comments - some good examples in there.